# Add button below expandable list and get all edit text value on this button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am creating a expandable list which has editText. Everything working fine, But i want to add   a button last of the page for search and want to get all fields value which i entered, But i don't know how to do in this code. I found this code on internet.

Here is my class:-

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class SearchProduct extends ExpandableListActivity {
            MyExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setList();
            }

            public void setList() {
                final int LIST_SIZE = 3;
                List<String> groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<List<String>> childList1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                List<List<String>> childList2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                List<String> childData = new ArrayList<String>();
                childData.add("");
                //for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
                {
                    groupList.add("Category Name:");
                    childList1.add(childData);
                    childList2.add(childData);
                    groupList.add("Product Name: ");
                    childList1.add(childData);
                    childList2.add(childData);
                    groupList.add("Colour: ");
                    childList1.add(childData);
                    childList2.add(childData);
                    groupList.add("Brand: ");
                    childList1.add(childData);
                    childList2.add(childData);

                }
                mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(groupList, childList1,
                        childList2);
                setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
                private List<String> groups;
                private List<List<String>> childs1;
                private List<List<String>> childs2;
                private boolean isFocusEditText1 = true;
                private LayoutInflater inflater;

                public MyExpandableListAdapter(List<String> groups,
                        List<List<String>> childs1, List<List<String>> childs2) {
                    this.groups = groups;
                    this.childs1 = childs1;
                    this.childs2 = childs2;
                    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                }

                public int getRowId(int groupPosition) {
                    return groupPosition;
                }

                public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                    return childs1.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                }

                public Object getChild2(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                    return childs2.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                }

                public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                    return childPosition;
                }

                public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                    return childs1.get(groupPosition).size();
                }

                public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    Log.d("getChildView", "groupPosition = " + groupPosition
                            + ", childPosition = " + childPosition + ", isLastChild = "
                            + isLastChild + ", convertView = " + convertView
                            + ", ViewGroup = " + parent);
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_product, parent,
                                false);
                    }
                    EditText editText1 = (EditText) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
                    editText1
                            .setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                    Log.d("onFocusChanged1", "View : " + v
                                            + ", hasFocus : " + hasFocus);
                                    if (hasFocus)
                                        isFocusEditText1 = true;
                                }
                            });
                /*  EditText editText2 = (EditText) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
                    editText2
                            .setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                    Log.d("onFocusChanged2", "View : " + v
                                            + ", hasFocus : " + hasFocus);
                                    if (hasFocus)
                                        isFocusEditText1 = false;
                                }
                            });
                    if (isFocusEditText1)
                        editText1.requestFocus();
                    else
                        editText2.requestFocus();
                    */
                    return convertView;
                }

                public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                    return groups.get(groupPosition);
                }

                public int getGroupCount() {
                    return groups.size();
                }

                public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                    return groupPosition;
                }

                public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    Log.d("getGroupView", "groupPosition = " + groupPosition
                            + ", isExpanded = " + isExpanded + ", convertView = "
                            + convertView + ", ViewGroup = " + parent);
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, parent,
                                false);
                    }
                    if (convertView instanceof TextView) {
                        ((TextView) convertView).setText(getGroup(groupPosition)
                                .toString());
                    }
                    return convertView;
                }

                public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                    return true;
                }

                public boolean hasStableIds() {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

here is my search.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:textColor="#fff"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingLeft="48dip" />
```

here is my search_product.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="64dip"
                  android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
                android:paddingRight="12dip" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#C0C0C0"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />

                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so you want simply put search option for expandablelistview?

Comment: But there is no expandable list view. Please check the code above.

Comment: because its extends ExpandableListActivity.. which is for expandable listview.

Comment: Sorry i am new in android, Will you please explain how i can do this?

Comment: follow this link http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html

Comment: This is an auto complete list. I don't want this. I just wanted to enter a text and when i click on button i like to pass these value to the server.

Comment: then simply replace editext with autocomplete and on button click send text of edittext to server.